# How to adjust the CSS in for desktop but below another item for tablet

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

So I have created a grid layout where I want the button to be aligned in the same row while on desktop, but stack where the search bar is on one row and the rest of the row below it with some space on the left side and then for mobile the FilterButtons stacked on top of each other. I've so many different combinations but I don't know what I'm missing. So far, I have it looking correctly for desktop.

Here is the sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-grid-u5uuud?file=/src/Responsive.jsx

So far I have this:

```
<Grid item lg={12} sm={12} xs={12} sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
            <Grid container spacing={2} height="100%">
              <Grid item lg={6} sm={6} xs={6} display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="start">
                <Typography fontSize={"20px"}>Applications</Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item lg={6} sm={6} xs={6} display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="end">
                <Button sx={appStyle.newAppButton}>+ New Application</Button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item lg={12} sm={12} xs={12} >
            <Grid container spacing={0} height="100%">
              <Grid item lg={3} sm={12} xs={12} display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="start">
                <TextField
                  type="search"
                  variant="outlined"
                  margin="normal"
                  fullWidth
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <SearchIcon />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item lg={6} sm={0} xs={0} /> {/* empty column */}
              <Grid item lg={2} sm={9.9} xs={12} display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="end">
                <FilterButton label="Product" options={productOptions} />
                <FilterButton label="Application Status" options={applicationStatusOptions} />
                <FilterButton label="Ticket Status" options={ticketStatusOptions} />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item lg={1} sm={1} xs={1} display="flex" alignItems="right" justifyContent="end">
                <Button style={{ fontSize: "14px", width: "150px", whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>Clear All Filters</Button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
```

Here's what it should look like for tablet:
[image]

Here's what it should look like for mobile phone:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `FilterButtons` inside one `Grid` and change `flex-direction` according to screen width. Similarly wrap the `FilterButtons` and `Clear All Filter` Button under one `Grid` and change it's flex-direction also.

##### Example -

```js
/*
 * Styles for filterButton Grid
 */
const StyledFilterButtonGrid = styled(Grid)`
  display: flex;
  min-width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 0px;
  & > * {
    background-color: white;
  }

  /* For Desktop screen */
  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
`;

/** Styles for FilterButtons and Clear All Button Grid */
const StyledFilters = styled(Grid)`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-block-start: 0.5em;

  /* Small Mobile Screen */
  @media (max-width: 400px) {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: start;
    gap: 1em;
  }
`;
```

You can find the sandbox code here

[image: Edit Responsive Grid (forked)]

##### Demo Screenshots

###### Mobile Screen

[image]

###### Desktop Screen

[image]

###### Smaller Mobile Screen

[image]

#### ------------------------------- Update ---------------------------------

For aligning the search box and other filter buttons on desktop mode, you can provide appropriate values to `lg` attribute `TextField Grid` and `SearchFilters Grid`.
I've updated the code over sandbox.

###### Updated Desktop Screen

[image]

Comment: This is almost perfect however now on desktop they are not on the same line, can you please adjust that?

Comment: Basically what's wrong is that your tablet and desktop version are the same however your tablet and mobile version look perfect but I'm struggling to get the search bar and rest of the buttons on the same line for desktop versions

Comment: @AngelaRubchinksy find the updated code.